# Is it possible to replace mat-expansion-panel-header with mat-form-field in mat-accord?

Tags: angular, angular-material

The idea is to have mat-accordion functionality but I would like to use mat-form-field as the box where user can select options.

what I have at the moment is this:
[image]

but I would like to use mat-form-field like this:
[image]

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can't you use the select component? https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: Or the autocomplete component? https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: Idea is to have that accordion effect with the right arrow. When it is open, arrow up, when it is closed, arrow down. And I have no idea how to have that effect with select or autocomplete.

Comment: So basically, you want the animation of the accordion on the select or auto complete?

Comment: yes, you can say that

Comment: You can try to use the autocomplete element anyway, and use css keyframes to animate the dropdown

Comment: is there any way to disable autocomplete text typing option?

Comment: I don't really understand that design of yours. On the second shot, it looks like this is an input field I can type. So why would disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>
          Lorem ispum
        </mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="inputFormControl">
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
    <p>No, you are not dude</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

And modify the style of the mat-form-field to fit in the `mat-expansion-panel`.